# Visual Basic 2010 Editable Values On Combobox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, combobox

Hi guys i want to ask you something. i have created a project in visual basic 2010 with a combobox. I have added some values in it but when i 'run' it (with F5) everyone can type his own text in the combobox.. i just want the user who will be using this program, to have to choose one value from the list and cant write something else. Is it an option at properties of combobox or i must write a code? Please help, Thanks.

Comment: What u wanna say here?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773430/vb-net-how-to-prevent-user-input-in-a-combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `DropDownStyle` property from `DropDown` to `DropDownList`. This changes your ComboBox (=dropdownlist combined with a text field) to function as  a pure dropdownlist.